# Future from multiprocessing.Pool.apply

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-3.6

Looking at `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async` I was expecting it to return a Future. Sadly it seems callback based.

Now if I would like to call `multiprocessing.Pool.apply` but have it wrapped in a Future (so it gets processed asynchronously), is this possible somehow?

Comment: Have you considered using concurrent.futures Pools instead?

Comment: AFAIK this means having to comply to GIL.

Answer (score 1):

The `multiprocessing.Pool` class is the old Python implementation of the Process based Pool of Workers. It was designed before the `concurrent.futures` module.

The `apply_async` method returns a `ApplyResult` object which acts similarly to the `Future` one.

If you want to stick to `Future` objects, you need to use the [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent.futures#processpoolexecutor) which, as the name says, it's process based. Therefore, it's not affected by the GIL.

If you need more advanced functionalities such as the support for initializer functions or timeouts you can have a look at [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble).